# Objective-C Object Init

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, cocos2d-iphone

I am still a bit confused by Objective-C object initialisation. Im used to nice clean object inheritance in other languages like (don’t kill me) ActionScript.

Here is an example, and I would like to know if (a) its the correct way of doing it, (b) why doesn’t `init` get called when I call `initWithLevel`?

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // Code to create game background.
        // Code to create game board.
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithLevel:(NSDictionary*)level {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // Code to populate game board
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps have a look at ["Multiple initialisers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MultipleInitializers.html) in the "Cocoa Core Competencies" guide, in particular the concept of a "Designated Initializer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method will be called only if you call it (except delegates/notifications, it'll be called according to the events) !!!

You are calling `initWithLevel` not `init`.

You need to write a separate method for the initialization like:

```
- (id) init
{
    return [self initWithLevels:nil];
}

- (id) initWithLevel:(NSDictionary*)level
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        [self configureGameboard:level];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)configureGameboard:(NSDictionary*)level
{
   // Code to create game background.
   // Code to create game board.
}
```

Refer [Designated Initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MultipleInitializers.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense... looking back at my code... i can see it is calling `self = [super init]`. So my defined init does not get called, only the parents! P.S. is there a typo on your code where you have `self = [self init]`? E.g. you are using self rather than super?

Comment: @DigitalJohn: I noticed that and fixed that too. :)

Comment: Only *one* init method (the "designated initialiser") should call the super init method.

Comment: @MartinR: I modified the answer based on the [Designated Initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MultipleInitializers.html)

Comment: As I understand it, the designated initializer should be the most specialized one, in this case initWithLevel.

Comment: This is backwards -- `initWithLevel:` should call `[super init]`, and `init` should call `initWithLevel:`. Please read Apple's documentation on designated initializers.

Comment: @MidhunMP One more suggestion -- consider renaming `initMyObjects` `configureGameboard`, or something similar; method names prefixed with `init` should follow the conventions for initializer methods.

Comment: @MidhunMP Sorry, one more thing: your `initWithLevel:` method is ignoring the argument. You might want to insert a comment to the effect of "Do something with level here" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

(a) its the correct way of doing it ?

if the `initWithLevel` is the designated initializer for your class, then yes it's the correct way you are doing it but you should add other initialisation in the same methode.

like this :

```
- (instancetype) initWithLevel:(NSDictionary*)level {
        self = [super init];
        if (self != nil) {
         // Code to create game background.
          // Code to create game board.
           // Code to populate game board
        }
        return self;
    }
```

elsewhere you should call your designated initializer like this :

```
- (instancetype) initWithLevel:(NSDictionary*)level {
    self = [self init];
    if (self != nil) {

        // Code to populate game board
    }
    return self;
}
```

and in your `init` ( designated initializer ):

```
- (instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // Code to create game background.
        // Code to create game board.
    }
    return self;
}
```

> (b) why doesn’t init get called when i call initWithLevel ?

Because in your `initWithLevel` method you are calling the super's `init` and not the self's `init`.

if your `initWithLevel` is the disignated initializer, you can also add an Exception to the `init` method to avoid creating a game without level. something like this :

```
- (instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
       @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"WallSafeInitialization"
                                       reason:@"Use initWithLevel: not init"
                                     userInfo:nil];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Initializers should be chained together. Also, consider defaulting the level rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: I don't think that throwing an exception is always wrong, but it might be best to create the object with default values, but i am sure that there are situations witch is not logic to put default values. For example if i have a Class Book and an initWithBookISBN: method.Creating a book with a default ISBN has no sense, in this case for example, i prefer throwing an exception in the init.@jlehr What do you think ?

Comment: According to Apple's documentation, `init…` methods must "return the initialized object or, if initialization did not succeed, return `nil`."

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer. I am confused because i have seen this code ( Throwing an exception in the init method) in an iOS book written by a famous Cocoa developers (By Joe Conway and Aaron Hillegass), IOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide.

Comment: There may be edge cases where it's arguably appropriate to throw an exception in an initializer method, but that's a non-trivial topic that isn't relevant to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

From [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MultipleInitializers.html):

> #### The Designated Initializer
>
> The initializer of a class that takes the full complement of initialization parameters is usually the
> designated initializer. The designated initializer of a subclass must
> invoke the designated initializer of its superclass by sending a
> message to super. The convenience (or secondary) initializers—which
> can include init—do not call super. Instead they call (through a
> message to self) the initializer in the series with the next most
> parameters, supplying a default value for the parameter not passed
> into it. The final initializer in this series is the designated
> initializer.

So according to Apple's documentation, your initialization methods should be chained together as follows:

```
- (id)init {
    return [self initWithLevel:nil]; // Consider passing a default dictionary instead of nil.
}

// Designated initializer
//
- (id)initWithLevel:(NSDictionary *)level {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // Code to populate game board
    }
    return self;
}
```

Your `init` implementation could provide a more meaningful argument than `nil` if it makes sense in the context of your app -- for example a dictionary of game board values for level 1 as a default value.